# Pandas read_xml does not work when no attributes are in an element

Tags: pandas, xml, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have the following code, and it keeps erroring out with "ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath."

I have tried a few things but still wouldn't work. Any ideas please?

```
import pandas as pd

sample_xml = '<Application Type="NewApplication" xmlns:pa="urn:Applyonline-Product-Attributes"><loanappBatch>some_data_here</loanappBatch></Application>'

df = pd.read_xml(
    sample_xml,
    xpath='.//pa:Application/pa:loanappBatch',
    namespaces={'pa': 'urn:Applyonline-Product-Attributes'}
)

print(df)
```

I am expecting no errors and for the dataframe to show one field with "some_data_here" as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use below code snippet .

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
sample_xml = '<Application Type="NewApplication" xmlns:pa="urn:Applyonline-Product-Attributes"><loanappBatch>some_data_here</loanappBatch></Application>'


root = ET.fromstring(sample_xml)
loanappBatch = root.find('.//{urn:Applyonline-Product-Attributes}loanappBatch').text
df = pd.DataFrame({'loanappBatch': [loanappBatch]})
print(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things are the issue of your implementation of [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html):

- Root does not use the namespace prefix: `pa`.
- Your `xpath` returns the text value source and not the collection of elements. Per docs:

  > XPath should return a collection of elements and not a single element.

  One way to think about this is your ultimate column(s) should not be in the xpath but its parent should.

Therefore to fix, simply adjust the `xpath` to root level which does not require namespace assignment, to migrate all its children to columns and rows of data frame:

```
df = pd.read_xml(sample_xml, xpath='./Application')
```